# Show total when displaying Rank within a Group

Tags: excel, rank

How can I display the total that a value is ranked when ranking by group?

[rank example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnzFI.png)

I would like to display the total number of people the person is ranked against, as seen here in this pic:
[how i want company rank displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBNHT.png)

In other terms, if a group of 3 employees is ranked, I want their rank to be shown as 1/3, 2/3, or 3/3.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate your rank formula with a countif().  Like so.

```
=CONCATENATE(rank(stuff),"/",COUNTIF(B$5:B$10,B5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following array formula:

```
=MATCH(C2,LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$C$2:$C$7),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2)))),0) & "/" & COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2)
```

Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode. When done correctly Excel will automatically put {} around the formula to denote an array formula.

[image]

Comment: This worked! How can I modify this formula to ignore errors such as "#N/A" in column C from your picture above?

Comment: @imnatron that is a new question, but I would deal with the error in column C by using an `IFERROR() wrapper and make it equal to 0 instead.